# How to shift time to half an hour ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the following functions to get orders in hast 3/half hours:

```
 def send_last_3hours_ordered_sku
        time = k = 3.hours.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_time + 5.hours + 30.minutes # for IST time
        title = "Sku Ordered since (#{time.to_s})"
        os = Order.where("completed_at > ?", time).where("state = 'complete'")
        Notification.send_email_to_help({:title => title, :attachment_name => title+".csv", :attachment => Admin::OrderQueryController.make_sku_csv(os)}).deliver         
    end

    def send_last_half_hour_ordered_sku
        time = k = 0.5.hours.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_time + 5.hours + 30.minutes # for IST time
        title = "Sku Ordered since (#{time.to_s})"
        os = Order.where("completed_at > ?", time).where("state = 'complete'")
        Notification.send_email_to_help({:title => title, :attachment_name => title+".csv", :attachment => Admin::OrderQueryController.make_sku_csv(os)}).deliver         
    end
```

The function for 3 hours works fine, but the one for half hours does not. Instead of orders completed in the last half hour, it returns all the orders in that day.

I also tried using:

```
#1.
time = k = 30.minutes.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_time + 5.hours + 30.minutes # for IST time
#this gives the same result
#2.
time = k = 30.mins.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_time + 5.hours + 30.minutes # for IST time
#This gives an error : undefined method `mins' for 30:Fixnum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of,

```
 time = k = 0.5.hours.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_time + 5.hours + 30.minutes
```

use

```
 time = k = 30.minutes.ago.in_time_zone(TZInfo::Timezone.get('Asia/Kolkata'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is that rails can handle time zones on it's own, but it tends to be tricky in practice, where sometimes DB is not utc etc. Rule of thumb is that  something as simple as:

`Order.where("completed_at > ?", 30.minutes.ago.to_s(:db)).where(state: 'complete')`

should work for you.

If you still get wrong time, you might try solution from this article - (it might help you understand the workings of the time zones in rails) http://chris.finne.us/2011/09/23/rails-3-tosdb-when-database-time-is-not-utc/